# Find smallest $x$ such that $a^x \equiv b \bmod p$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, optimization, algorithms, problem-solving

> **Problem:** How do we find smallest $x$ such that $a^x \equiv b \bmod p$, where $p$ is a prime and $1 \le b,a \le p$ and $a$, $b$, and $p$ are given and fixed. If there is no such $x$, how do we check it ?

Brute force approach is to iterate over all $x$ starting from $1$ up till when $a^x\equiv 1 \bmod p$ and return the smallest such $x$ if exists.

Is there some closed formula to solve these kinds of equations ?

Comment: If there were a closed formula, a lot of cryptographers would be very upset.

Comment: Are `a`, `b`, and `p` all given, or are we free to choose one or more of them?  If they are given, I think `a^x = 1 mod p` should be `a^x =` **b** `mod p`?

Comment: As already commented by Sal any closed formula would cause the collapse of lot of encryption scheme that rests on the computational difficulty of the "Discrete Logarithm Problem"

Comment: @2012rcampion no it's correct. They are suggesting an algorithm for finding the smallest positive integer $x$ such that $a^x \equiv b\mod p$. To do this, they check all values of $x$ from 1 onwards, until they they find such an $x$. However the values of $a^x$ modulo $p$ repeat after $a^x$ is congruent to 1 modulo $p$, so if no solution is found before then, there are none.

Comment: @PVa, not if the closed formula was computationally infeasible.

Comment: Yes, sometimes explicit formula or closed formula is not exactly computationally usable: the formula for Euler's totient in terms of  prime power factorisation.

Answer (score 1):

There is an explicit formula  for  the discrete logarithm:

$$x=\log_a b=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p-2} \frac{b^i}{1-a^{i}} \mod{p}.$$

See, the [thesis](http://math.ucdenver.edu/graduate/thesis/dreiff.pdf) , Theorem 3.2

Comment: Proof? Citation?

Comment: I added a link,  but it is a well known result.

Comment: $7^3 \text{ mod } 11 = 2<> \sum_{i=1}^{11-2} \frac{2^i}{1-7^{i}} \text{ mod } 11 = 10,55$
???